# Какие таблицы есть в БД социальной сети?

Tags: база-данных, соцсети

Если делать социальную сеть, то как должна быть устроена БД. Я думаю, что есть минимум 4 таблицы:

1. Хранит id и индивидуальные настройки
2. Хранит id и данные(Имя, фамилия, вуз и т.п.)
3. Хранит id и посты на стене
4. Хранит id и подписки

Все таблицы связаны внешнем ключем id

Нормальна ли такая структура? Если ты находишься в новостях, то через 4 таблицу по id вынимает все подписки и берет у каждого сообщения из 3 таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблицы 1 и 2 в вашем варианте можно объединить — это одна "суть": пользователь.

Подписки занимают небольшой объём и свойственны Пользователю, и пока интересны тоже только ему. Ведь не будет частого поиска "кто подписан на X?" Я бы их тоже хранил в таблице про Пользователя, в текстовом поле, через запятую. Настройки тоже можно упихнуть в одно поле в сериализованном виде.

Итого:

1. Пользователи (id, имя, фамилия, ..., подписки "13,15,17,19", настройки);
2. Посты (post_id, user_id, тест).

Вопрос в том, как вы захотите наворачивать функционал дальше. Группы, паблики, рекламный движок, приложения?

Comment: @sergiks я не понял про посты, вы хотите сделать одну таблицу постов на весь сайт? Постов же будет миллион. И потом надо будет вытащить все посты определенной подписки

Comment: Миллион это немного. Потом расширение проекта поручите кому-нибудь, кто разбирается в шардинге и вуду магии.

Поясните, что такое "подписка".

Comment: Ну вот в ВК / Твиттере, когда вы нажимаете у какого-то пользователя "Подписаться" / "Читать"  его посты будут отображаться на вашей странице в хронологическом порядке. Если много у вас подписок, то эти посты будут разные

Comment: и как это меняет суть? подписка для одного, все равно, что посты для хозяина.А новостная лента соответственно - слить подписки и отсортировать их по дате.

Comment: А если еще есть понравившиеся, заметки и т.п. Их тоже сохранять в первой таблице через запятую?

Comment: мне кажется проще создать отдельную таблицу для этого, если через запятую, то нужно разбивать и циклом крутить, неудобно